# How to setup formula

Tags: apex, formula

How to create a new field  and setup as a formula to pick up from Dealer region in account Object.

Comment: Can you explain this bit more?

Comment: we have accounta and Account vehicle ownership object .now i want to create a new field  called Selling dealership region in Account Vehicle ownership Object to pick up from dealer region from account object.

Comment: relation between  account and Account vehicle ownership object?

Comment: master detail relation

Comment: we have accounts and vehicle objects to link accounts and vehicles we have Account vehicle ownership object.

Comment: sravya, rather than answer in the comments, could you edit/update your question to reflext your full, well described question ? Doing so will make it more clear to others what your exact question is, and not hide info in the comments where it's less likely to be seen.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a cross object formula. To do this perform the following actions.

1. From Salesforce Click *Setup*
2. From setup menu expand *Create*
3. Select *Objects*, then click on your Account Vehicle Ownership object.
4. Scroll down to the field section *Custom Fields* and click the *New* button.
5. Select formula from the field types and click *Next* then select text and click *Next*.
6. In the *Advanced Formula* view for the formula you can reference a field on another object by clicking the *Insert Field* button.
7. You need to select the field which references the Account on the Account Vehicle Ownership object.
8. Select the Dealer Region from the account object.
9. Click save and add to appropriate page layout, set permissions etc.

I suggest you refer to this [link](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=fields_creating_cross_object_advanced.htm&language=en_US) for more info and read up on formula field types.